# How to determine of the left mouse button was clicked-visual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mouse

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2012, and I want to check to see if the left mouse button was clicked during a loop.
For example,

```
boolean click1=false;
while (!click1)
{
    // if the left mouse button is clicked, change click1 to true
}
```

How can I check if the button was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use WinForms or WPF? I think you need some Threading there.

Anyway you should have a look on Backgroundworker class.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: I'm using WinForms. I honestly have no idea what threading is, but I'll take a look at the link. Thanks for the help!